# Updating to non-standard database in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using *Django Rest Framework*, how to execute update/PUT calls to a non-standard database?

In my Django project I'm using a separate database for the application data:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'bookstore': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'bookstore.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I use the **ModelSerializer** and **ModelViewSet** to automatically create the API for me. I loop over the models to automatically generate all the Serializers and ViewSets (quite a big number of tables), the generated classes end up looking like this:

ModelSerializer:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

ModelViewSet:

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.using('bookstore').all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

I needed to add the `using('bookstore')` here to make this work.
Reading (GET) works fine. When I try to do a PUT update, I get a `no such table: book` Sqlite error.

It seems like the update isn't routed to the bookstore database.

For completeness, I use these loops to generate the ModelSerializer and ModelViewSets from the models:

ModelSerializer, generator:

```
models = dict(apps.all_models['api'])

for name, model in models.items():       
    class_name = name[:1].upper() + name[1:] + 'Serializer'
    Meta = type('Meta', (object, ), {'model': model, 'fields': '__all__'})

    print(class_name)
        globals()[class_name] = type(class_name, (serializers.ModelSerializer,), {'Meta':Meta, })
```

ModelViewSet, generator:

```
models = dict(apps.all_models['api'])
for name, model in models.items():
    capitalized_class_name = name[:1].upper() + name[1:]
    viewset_class_name = capitalized_class_name + 'ViewSet'
    serializer_class_name = capitalized_class_name + 'Serializer'
    globals()[viewset_class_name] = type(viewset_class_name, (viewsets.ModelViewSet,), {'queryset': model.objects.using('bookstore').all(), 'serializer_class': globals()[serializer_class_name],'filter_backends': [filters.OrderingFilter], })
```

Comment: You'll need to implement a `create` or `update` method in the serializer to use the appropriate database.

Comment: but how to do this in a way that's generic, so you don't have to create an create/update method for each different table (as each table has different fields); is it somehow possible to super() the underlying ModelSerializer create/update method and inject a database name? -- it's been a while since I've worked with Python -- but I remember something like this used to be possible..

Comment: that would be up to you to figure out.  Personally, I feel relying on multiple databases adds a significant level of complexity that only apply to a limited number of use cases.  to start with, I'd do some re-evaluation in whether multiple data sources is really a requirement, and whether the complexity is worth it.

Comment: As a database modeller I had never really liked using ORM, but using Django I gave it a shot just to see. Django is in my project is only there as api layer between the database and the front-end. I now found the *perfect* solution in PostgREST. It does everything DRF does, but more and better. Supports composite PK's and nested relations, no more needing to specify your model twice (database and models.py). What took me hours in DRF, literally was done in PostgREST in minutes. I am loving this! It's not really an answer to this specific question, but I've moved away from DRF to PostgREST now!

Comment: postgrest has a few good things for it, but it gives me the willies.  reason is, its exposing everything in the db to the endpoints, and kills any kind of business logic.  About the only use I could see for it is for locked down internal use, and never, ever expose the API out to the wild.

Comment: That's a valid point, but in my particular scenario that's not really an issue. I think I did read in the documentation that they have private schema's to address this topic, but I've not explored that yet.